# javascript works in firefox but not in ie

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, firefox

I cant get this code to work in ie.  It doesn't throw any errors or warnings.  I'm stuck.  Help anyone?  (Line 28 is the part that isn't working).  If the result of the the second ajax section fails, the alert box will pop up just fine, but if it is successful, it won't insert the users email into the input box called 'donorEmail'.

```
  function getEmail(ticketID) {  

  // find email based on first and last name.

  var donor = $('#q').val();

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "action.php",
    data: {field: 'donorID', donor:donor },
    async: false,
    success: function (result) {
                if(result != 0) {
                    document.getElementById("donorID").value = Number(result);
                } else {
                    document.getElementById("donorID").value = '0';
                }
            },
    error: function (result) {
                pass = "error"
                alert("There was an error with the database");
            }
  });       

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "action.php",
    data: {field: 'donorEmail', donor:donor },
    async: false,
    success: function (result) {
                if(result != 0) {
                    document.getElementById("donorEmail").value = result;
                } else {
                    alert("No email on file for this donor");
                    document.getElementById("donorEmail").value = '';
                }
            },
    error: function (result) {
                pass = "error"
                alert("There was an error with the database");
            }
  });
}
```

Comment: Which version of IE?

Comment: What version of IE? I'm pretty sure most recent versions have a *Network* console tab so inspect the response from your second call to `action.php`. I'd also make sure you only have **one** element with `id="donorEmail"`

Comment: Also, watch out for elements with `name="donorEmail"`. Apparently some versions of IE treat `name` and `id` the same in `getElementById` ~ http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200802/beware_of_id_and_name_attribute_mixups_when_using_getelementbyid_in_internet_explorer/

Comment: validate that document.getElementById("donorEmail") actually returns something

Comment: @code4jhon—if it didn't, the OP would get an error, which apparently doesn't occur.

Comment: don't need 2 requests for this, use one and return json with both values. Also ***do not use*** `async:false` it is terrible practice and is being deprecated by browser vendors

Comment: Try putting a semicolon at the end of the assignments to the variable `pass`. Also, don't forget to check the console for errors.

Comment: ie version 11 on the browser.  What does async:false actually do?  It was just in the code that I was using as an example so I left it there.